# URL parameter missing in chrome.tabs query (using Manifest V3)

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

My `manifest.json` is as follows:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "My Extension",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Description",
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "activeTab"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*"
    ],
    "icons": {
      "16": "assets/icon16.png",
      "48": "assets/icon48.png",
      "128": "assets/icon128.png"
    }
  }
```

Here is the code within the component:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  let tabs = await this.getTabs();
  console.log("TABS", tabs);
}

async getTabs() {
  let queryOptions = { active: true, currentWindow: true };
  let tabs = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
  return tabs;
}
```

This outputs an array of length 1, which contains this tab object:

```
active: true
audible: false
autoDiscardable: true
discarded: false
groupId: -1
height: 795
highlighted: true
id: 778819291
incognito: false
index: 8
mutedInfo: {muted: false}
openerTabId: 778819275
pinned: false
selected: true
status: "complete"
width: 1440
windowId: 778818183
```

The `url` property doesn't seem to exist in this. Any insights on why that is?

Thank you!

Comment: You probably look at and old error in chrome://extensions UI. Click the trashcan icon to remove it and use devtools instead: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: Yep, this was it. Rebuilding the extension wasn't enough. I needed to remove and install it again. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solution (thanks to wOxxOm):

Rebuilding was not enough after updating permissions. I needed to delete the extension and install/load it again